# Processing time for my Spark program does not decrease on increasing the number of nodes in the cluster

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, cloudera

I have a Cloudera cluster with 3 nodes on which Apache Spark is installed. I am running a Spark program which reads data from HBase tables, transforms the data and stores it in a different HBase table. With 3 nodes the time taken in approximately 1 minutes 10 seconds for 5 million rows HBase data. On decreasing or increasing the number of nodes, the time taken came similar whereas it was expected to reduce after increasing the number of nodes and increase by increasing the number of nodes.Below was the time taken:

1) With 3 nodes: Approximately 1 minute 10 seconds for 5 million rows.
 2) With 1 node: Approximately 1 minute 10 seconds for 5 million rows.
 3) With 6 nodes: Approximately 1 minute 10 seconds for 5 million rows.

What can be the reason for same time taken despite increasing or decreasing the number of nodes?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Hbase will probably read the 5 million rows from a single region or maybe 2 regions (degree of parallelism).  The write will occur to a single region or maybe 2 based on the scale of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Is Spark your bottleneck? If you allocate variable resources (more/less cores or memory) it will only lead to change in overall times of the job if the computation on the job is the bottleneck.

If your computation (the transform) is relatively simple, the bottleneck might be reading from HBase or writing from HBase. In that case irrespective of how many node/cores you may give it. The run time will be constant.

From the runtimes you have mentioned it seems that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck may be one or both hbase and spark side. You can check the hbase side for your tables number of region servers. It is same meaning with the read and write parallelism of data. The more the better usually. You must notice [the hotspotting issue](https://sematext.com/blog/2012/04/09/hbasewd-avoid-regionserver-hotspotting-despite-writing-records-with-sequential-keys/)

The spark side parallelism can be checked with your number of rdd for your data. May be you should repartition your data. Added to this,cluster resource utilization may be your problem. For checking this you can monitor spark master web interface. Number of nodes, number of workers per node, and number of job, task per worker etc. Also you must check number of cpu and amont of ram usage per worker within this interface.
For details [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)